# HTTP audio streaming Android < 3.0 (Vitamio)

Tags: android, audio-streaming, vitamio

I want to play streaming audio by HTTP (m3u8) on Android 2.2 and higher. With Android 3.0 and above, HTTP streaming is supported, only below 3.0 it doesn't.

A solution is to use the Vitamio in the project. But, Vitamio requires the user to install a plugin from the Play store.

So, my questions:
- Is there any way to embed the Vitamio plugin into the project?
- Is there another solution for HTTP streaming for devices < Android 3.0?

Answer (score 5):

Download the latest vitamio version. It allows developers to fully bundle Vitamio into their Android's APK, users don't need to download seperated plugins anymore.
Get it here: [Vitamio](http://vitamio.org/)
[image]
[image]
[image]
Go to add and select the vitamio bundle and click apply and you are done and you need not add vitamio in buildpath. Hope this helps.

Comment: But how do you actually embed it?  I tried to add vitamio.jar to my build path and that did not work - it just errored out non stop with the same error: http://vitamio.org/topics/59?locale=en

Comment: @Du3 For the latest version you need to add the vitamio workspace as library to your project.

Comment: @Du3 Edited the answer for you with images. Check it out.

Comment: Perfect.  Makes 100% sense and now its working.  Alternatively, I just downloaded the jar from here http://vitamio.org/vitamios/android-3-dot-0?locale=en and its working(well kinda, having other issues but I dont think its Vitamios fault).  Hope the OP accepts your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well this might be a bit late. But they have provided the decoders in their sdk. Just Download the Vitamio Bundle and import it in your project.

http://vitamio.org/vitamios?locale=en

"Part of Vitamio's source code is available at Github now! Please send your pull request!

Allow developers to fully bundle Vitamio into their Android's APK, users don't need to download seperated plugins anymore.
Remove unused code, keep the core classes only, such as MediaPlayer and MediaMetadataRetriever.
Support ARMv6, ARMv7, with VFP, VFPv3, NEON optimizations.
Open some source code to developers, VideoView, MediaController, and or interfaces are included."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago; I had to stream audio and video on <3.0, and from what I gathered Vitamio was the only decent solution.

As far as I know you can't embed the plugin, and the user always ends up with a "You need to install Vitamio" prompt which leads to their Google Play page.

Comment: Well that was way before, now they have embedded the decoders in the library and it works perfectly, only drawback is that you can customize there player and the app size is increased to more than 100% i.e to say that if your current app size is 3mb then with vitameo your app size will be around 8.5mb.